# Reading old German script about Henry Reimer

Tags: germany, birth-records

I found a DNA match to someone who has an ancestor Henry Reimer born about 1839, probably my 2G Grandparent Diderich Reimer's brother. They both immigrated to Cleveland, Ohio (separately).

These scripts are hard for me to read. I am using pattern recognition more than reading. I believe that I have a parent match, but I can't read the child's name. I am hoping that one of the forenames is Heinrich.

From Archion.de. Top record is my 2G Grandfather Diderich Reimer. Bottom record may be his brother Henry.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the names as I read them, and I think you have a match:

Record from 1833

> Johannes Joachim Friedrich Reimer, Weberknecht zu Beselin

> Sophia Christina Margarethe geb. Schröder

> Diderich Carl Christoph Johann Joachim Theodor

Record from 1840

> Johann Joachim Friedrich Reimer, Weber zu Fresendorf

> Sophia Christina Margarethe geb Schröder

> Christopher Heinrich Friedrich

"Weber" and "Weberknecht" both mean weaver. Fresendorf is quite close to Beselin (about 3km across the river Kösterbeck according to Google).